# time.minutes and time.seconds not defined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I made a work command with a cooldown that shows exactly how long you have to wait until you can work again. The cooldown works, but it says time.seconds and time.minutes is undefined. Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const db = require('quick.db')
const ms = require("ms");

module.exports = class economy {
  constructor(){
      this.name = 'work',
      this.alias = ['work'],
      this.usage = 's!work',
      this.description = 'Work to get paid',
      this.runnable = 'true'
}

async run(bot, message, args) {

let timeout = 600000 
let amount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 15;

var jobs = ["Miner", "Bartender", "Cashier", "Cleaner", "Drugdealer", "Assistant", "Nurse", "Cleaner", "Teacher", "Accountants", "Security Guard", "Sheriff", "Lawyer", "Dishwasher", "Electrician", "Singer", "Dancer"];

let work = await db.fetch(`work_${message.author.id}`);

if (work !== null && timeout - (Date.now() - work) > 0) {
    let time = ms(timeout - (Date.now() - work));

    message.channel.send(`You already worked, try again in **${time.minutes}m ${time.seconds}s**!`)
} else {
  var job = jobs[Math.floor(Math.random() * jobs.length)];

  message.channel.send(`You worked as a ${job} and earned ${amount} <:shart:646075915293687810>`)

db.add(`money_${message.author.id}`, amount)
db.set(`work_${message.author.id}`, Date.now())

}
}   
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [ms docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms), there are no `minutes` and `seconds` fields in the result from the `ms` function. If I understand your use case correctly, instead of `**${time.minutes}m ${time.seconds}s**` you should provide just `**{time}**`.

Comment: but how do I get the seconds then?

Comment: in a lot of bots I see time.minutes and time.seconds is used?

Comment: Take a look at [ms library code](https://github.com/zeit/ms/blob/master/index.js) - it is just rounds amount of the biggest unit (minutes in our case) and returns it with corresponding status.  If you want to show seconds anyway, you should consider another solution for this task (I am afraid, I can't provide at the moment)

Comment: You can check this solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-agnesi-ql3ef

Answer (score 0):

const ms = require("parse-ms")

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering a question but can you add some explanation on how your code solves the problem? (To correctly format code see this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)).